# What's a modern day equivalent of DinnerNow.net (for ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, web-standards

It's been almost 3 years since its release. Patterns come and go. We've seen some great advances in the ASP.NET world like MVC, Razor, and .NET 4 since DinnerNow.net's inception. Similarly for web standards, coffescript, LESS and so on.

What do you use as your golden example of best practice?

I'm particularly interested in how MVC fits in with n-tier architecture centered around Windows Workflow and would love an excellent design to go off rather than reinvent the wheel.

For reference: http://dinnernow.codeplex.com/

Comment: Don't forget [Project Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/), an ASP.NET CMS based on MVC 3 (AFAIK) made by (AFAIK) mostly people from Microsoft. Orchard is probably the opposite of NerdDinner. :)

Comment: Thanks bzlm! I'm actually using Orchard for the project I'm working on. It's alright, but has such great potential!

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

The modern day equivalent for ASP.NET MVC 3 is http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ which has a live site at: http://www.nerddinner.com/

It's written by some very capable guys including the likes of Scott Hanselman, Jon Galloway, Rob Conery, even Scott Guthrie etc: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/team/view

Comment: No worries. I see they have miniprofiler running and if you go to the My Dinners tab you will see they haven't optimised the SQL yet... lol!

Answer (score 1):

The MVC 3 Music Store is also an excellent example. With a publish date of April 2011 it may be more relevant.

[MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)

Comment: maybe for MVC 4 - WebAPI ?

Answer (score 1):

Sharp Lite https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite
or the full version
 http://www.sharparchitecture.net/